# How can i generate random variables using np.random.zipf for a given range of values?

Tags: python, random

I have a given price range and i had used random uniform to get random generated random results from it. How can i introduce `np.random.zipf` to do the same ?

i have tried the following :

```
a = np.random.zipf((randint(1, 6000000)), size=None)
print(a)
```

But it seems to be providing no return values, and it keeps running the code without any termination

```
order_total_price_range1 = round(random.uniform(850, 560000), 5)
order_total_price_range2 = round(random.uniform(850, 560000), 5)
```

I expected to get max and min values from the `zipf` distribution, but currently not getting any results returned.

Comment: Could state what your problem is exactly ? Am I right to say that you want to generate random prices within a given interval.

Comment: @RobinNicole yes that is exactly what i meant to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @RobinNicole is right wrt Zipf distribution, you could simulate truncated Zipf using discrete sampling. Along the lines

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def Zipf(a: np.float64, min: np.uint64, max: np.uint64, size=None):
    """
    Generate Zipf-like random variables,
    but in inclusive [min...max] interval
    """
    if min == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError("")

    v = np.arange(min, max+1) # values to sample
    p = 1.0 / np.power(v, a)  # probabilities
    p /= np.sum(p)            # normalized

    return np.random.choice(v, size=size, replace=True, p=p)

min = np.uint64(3)
max = np.uint64(8)

q = Zipf(1.2, min, max, 10000)
print(q)

h, bins = np.histogram(q, bins = int(max-min+1),range=(min-0.5,max+0.5))
print(h)
print(bins)

plt.hist(q, bins = bins)
plt.title("Zipf")
plt.show()
```

Will make graph like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tune the parameter of the Zipf law to restrict it to a given interval as you do it with the uniform distribution. The reason for that is that the Zipf distribution is always defined on the set of all the positive integers independently of its parameters.

Comment: If i want a zipf distribution for dates, is that possible? i know this might be stupid question, but since am new to this.