# Generating data of fixed size from a given set using Zipf probability distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, distribution, zipf

I need to generate data sets from a given set using discrete probability distributions like zipf, geometric etc.

For example, say we are given a set of elements A=(1,2,3,4,5), I need to generate a data set of size 100 such that;

-data set consist of elements of A

-the elements (1,2,3,4,5) are distributed in the data set according to zipf distribution with skew 2.

I can create data sets of fixed size with zipf distribution with the code below. However I cannot specify the elements of the data set.

```py
import numpy as np
#Zipf Random Variable
skew = 1.1
data = (np.random.zipf(skew, 100)).tolist()
print(data)

[35522089825, 3, 1, 1, 27, 351, 414182459, 324375076, 1, 3, 12, 1, 9, 3, 2134, 18, 1440, 1769, 11532, 4, 1, 48, 16943335127, 2090, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1692174747, 19722895802355, 22, 764140, 1454, 58246, 36, 1420773326, 209, 525, 1892, 1, 1149, 3198, 166, 75762805593897, 123, 12519, 3774, 1687, 445894, 4967, 34, 12043, 31263, 6874042139879332, 630392, 1229, 87, 1, 16, 1, 898089, 1, 18034617, 116812052, 14445, 9, 5, 78, 8, 1, 35, 1245582, 323183185139, 454, 7, 13545, 5, 2, 2283516, 10, 40524, 46, 208154651674, 31, 3, 397738, 3114, 78, 4434, 332483452, 3470095640, 386116, 11, 64982836, 17, 226309346, 4518013, 107016, 107486762068, 4]
```

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57413721/how-can-i-generate-random-variables-using-np-random-zipf-for-a-given-range-of-va/57420941#57420941 ?

Comment: Basically, you want bounded Zipf distribution, what you have in NumPy is unbounded one. Check my link above for sampling bounded zipf

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux  Unfortunately I have missed that answer while searching. Thank you so much, that helps a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. If you happy with the answer, bump it up