# Generate data with zipfian distribution and populate MySQL database with the data

Tags: python, mysql, numpy

I need to generate data that has a zipfian distribution and then populate a database with this set of generated data. If I have a MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
   id INT(11) PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   x INT(11) NOT NULL,
   ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

I want to generate data with zipfian distribution according to the variable 'x'. This variable has a range of 1 to 10. I used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57413721/how-can-i-generate-random-variables-using-np-random-zipf-for-a-given-range-of-va) to create the following python script:

```
 import numpy as np
 import pymysql


 def Zipf(a: np.float64, min: np.uint64, max: np.uint64, size=None):
     """
     Generate Zipf-like random variables,
     but in inclusive [min...max] interval
     """
     if min == 0:
         raise ZeroDivisionError("")
         v = np.arange(min, max+1) # values to sample
         p = 1.0 / np.power(v, a)  # probabilities
         p /= np.sum(p)            # normalized

         return np.random.choice(v, size=size, replace=True, p=p)

 min = np.uint64(1)
 max = np.uint64(10)

 q = Zipf(1.2, min, max, 100)
 # print(q)

 db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                 user="root",         # your username
                 passwd="password",  # your password
                 db="db2")        # name of the data base

 # you must create a Cursor object. It will let
 #  you execute all the queries you need
 cur = db.cursor()
 for i in q:
     cur.execute('INSERT INTO table1 (x) VALUES("%x")' % (int(i)) )
     db.commit()
```

This gives me the following error:

```
  File "/Users/alfie/PycharmProjects/zipfian/zipf.py", line 36, in <module>
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO table1 (x) VALUES("%x")' % (int(i)) )
  File "/Users/alfie/PycharmProjects/zipfian/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/alfie/PycharmProjects/zipfian/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Users/alfie/PycharmProjects/zipfian/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/Users/alfie/PycharmProjects/zipfian/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/Users/alfie/PycharmProjects/zipfian/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/Users/alfie/PycharmProjects/zipfian/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/Users/alfie/PycharmProjects/zipfian/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/Users/alfie/PycharmProjects/zipfian/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'a' for column 'x' at row 1")
```

If I use 3 and 8 as min and max as is done in the post that I linked there is no error and everything works. Also even when I change the range print(q) stilll works. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [execute](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html) takes an two arguments, a SQL string, and data. Don't use python string stuff to combine them.

Comment: Something like this? `val = []
cur = db.cursor()
for i in q:
    val.append(int(i))

sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (x) VALUES (%i)"
cur.execute(sql, val)` this gives me: `TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not str`

Comment: try `%s`, some documentation examples use this for numbers too. [executemany](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) may be an alternative to the loop if you have an array of tuples.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out! using dict I looked at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)

Comment: can you show your solution as an answer for the benefit of future SO users

Comment: yes of course! just posted the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the error by replacing the for loop with this:

```
for i in q:
    val = {
        'x': int(i)
    }
    sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (x) VALUES (%(x)s)"
    cur.execute(sql, val)
    db.commit()
```